# Change the zoom level of Google map in Jquery

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have tried the following code. Please let me know how can i change zoom level  inside the autocomplete of the textbox.

```
    var mobileDemo = { 'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 6 };              
    $('#places').live('pageinit', function() {
        demo.add('places_1', function() {
            $('#map_canvas_3').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                var self = this;
                console.log(self);
                var control = self.get('control', function() {
                    $(self.el).append('<div id="control"><div><input id="places-search" class="ui-bar-d ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-d ui-autocomplete-input" type="text"/></div></div>');
                    self.autocomplete($('#places-search')[0], function(ui) {
                        self.clear('markers');
                        self.set('bounds', null);
                        $("#map_canvas_3").gmap({'zoom':15});
                        $('#map_canvas_3').gmap('refresh');
                        //self.set('zoom', 15);
                        //self.gmap('refresh');
                        self.placesSearch({ 'location': ui.item.position, 'radius': '5000' }, function(results, status) {
                            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                                    self.addMarker({ 'id': item.id, 'position': item.geometry.location, 'bounds':true }).click(function() {
                                        self.openInfoWindow({'content': '<h4>'+item.name+'</h4>'}, this);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    return $('#control')[0];
                });
                self.addControl(new control(), 1);
            }});
        }).load('places_1');
    });
```

I have taken this code from 
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#places
I meant i have to change zoom level dynamically.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, it's not possible to use styling on code blocks because it could break people's code when posted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `mapname.setZoom(zoom)` should work where mapname is the name you gave the map when you created it and zoom the zoom level you want the map to have. For future reference, check out the [google maps api reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) (it's not particularly great, but it'll tell you stuff like that once you've got used to using the API).

Comment: That does work if you just put in a number but if you are trying to insert any kind of variable then for some reason it doesn't work....